# Recoger datos xml en php

Tags: php, javascript, xml

Buenas tardes, estoy realizando una web para mandar sms a los clientes, hasta ahora he conseguido que funcione usando la api que proporciona el servicio de sms contratado, vendría ser algo así:

```
<script>

function enviar(telefono,mensaje){
            //document.getElementById("frame_mensaje").src = "https://comunik.jmeservicios.com/api/sms?api_key=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx="+telefono+"&from=XXXXXX&message="+mensaje+"&gsm7=1";
        }

</script>

<iframe src="" name="frame_mensaje" id="frame_mensaje"></iframe>
```

... para simplificar, digamos que tenemos un frame con el src en blanco, que al hacer click en una tabla me devuelve el teléfono y el mensaje y los carga en la función enviar, que cambia el src del frame. Hasta ahí todo bien, el sms se envia y el frame me carga un xml de respuesta.

La API me permite también añadir (&callback_url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.urldecallback.com%3Fmy_delivery%3D333444), que entiendo que podría ser un php que recoge la respuesta xml, que viene en este formato:

```
<sms>

<status>SENT</status>

<credits>1</credits>

<remain>99952</remain>

<messages>

<message     jme_id="xxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-x-xxxxxxx"     to="+34xxxxxxxxx" status="SENT" type="sms"     credits="1" sms_count="1"     send_date="2015-01-12T12:00:59"/>

</messages>

</sms>
```

La pregunta es: ¿Cómo hago para convertir esta respuesta en variables php?. He buscado información y con la función "simplexml_load_string($archivo_xml)" puedo separar los datos del xml y asignarlos a variables, pero ¿Cómo cargo el xml en "$archivo_xml"?¿Cómo debería empezar ese archivo php que recoge la respuesta del servidor?

Me "defiendo" un poco en javascript y php... pero lo del xml es algo nuevo para mi. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Gracias a la respuesta de Jose Reynel he podido dar con una solución, espero que a alguien le ayude también:

-Página principal (index.php):

entre otras cosas....

```
<form id="form_mensaje" class="form-horizontal form-group-sm" method="post" action="respuesta.php" role="form" target="frame_mensaje">

    (aquí vendría el contenido que queremos pasar a la url)

    </form>

<iframe name="frame_mensaje" id="frame_mensaje"></iframe>
```

- Archivo "respuesta.php":

> ```
> > <?php 
> > 
> > $pagina_inicio = file_get_contents("url de la web que nos genera el
> > xml");
> > 
> > $xml = simplexml_load_string($pagina_inicio);
> > 
> > $estado = $xml->status;
> > 
> > echo $estado;
> > 
> > ?>
> ```

ya podemos darle forma al archivo "respuesta.php", tenemos los datos guardados en variables.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer una function que retorne un array con la data que requieres del xml de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php // librería que lee tu XML podria llamarse para el ejemplo script.php
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1); 
libxml_disable_entity_loader(false);
$arrTAGS = [];  


    $path = "path";//tu Path o ruta del XML, donde se encuentra el archivo .xml

    $xml = simplexml_load_file($path, 'SimpleXMLElement',LIBXML_NOWARNING);

if (is_array($xml) || is_object($xml) && !empty($xml))
    foreach ($xml as $nodo) 
    {
        $tagXML1          = $xml->tagXML1;  
        $tagXML2          = $xml->tagXML2;
        $tagXML3          = $xml->tagXML3;
        $tagXML4          = $xml->tagXML4;
        $tagXML5          = $xml->tagXML5;

        $arrTAGS["tagXML1"] = $tagXML1."";
        $arrTAGS["tagXML2"] = $tagXML2."";
        $arrTAGS["tagXML3"] = $tagXML3."";
        $arrTAGS["tagXML4"] = $tagXML4."";
        $arrTAGS["tagXML5"] = $tagXML5."";

        break;
    }
}

return $arrTAGS;

?>
```

para recoger los valores en algun lugar donde sea llamada tu libreria seria algo así:

```
<?php // sitio donde requieres que sea leida tu informacion del xml

    require_once('tuScript.php');

    $tagXML1 = (string)$arrTAGS["tagXML1"];
    $tagXML2 = (string)$arrTAGS["tagXML2"];
    $tagXML3 = (string)$arrTAGS["tagXML3"];
    $tagXML4 = (string)$arrTAGS["tagXML4"];
    $tagXML5 = (string)$arrTAGS["tagXML5"];

?>
```

Espero te sea de utilidad, saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, no he podido probar el ejemplo que me has puesto (no sabía como aplicarlo a lo que ya tenía hecho). Pero gracias a ello he podido solucionarlo de otra forma, me ha dado una buena pista... ;) (ahora pongo la solución que he usado)